# Python code to convert 1D tensor to 2D tensor

Tags: python, machine-learning, neural-network, pytorch, computer-vision

I am trying to use Binary Cross Entropy Loss (BCE loss) for Simese network.
I have two inputs for BCE loss function:

```
output (input_dy) → tensor of size [4] , output of neural network
true_labels (y_true) → tensor of size [4], target (true value)
```

For BCE loss, the input parameters must be of the dimension:

```
output (input_dy) → [Batch_size, no. of classes]
true_labels (y_true) → [Batch_size]
```

The following diagram explains the query:[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pzsnU.png)

I need a function in python using pytorch to convert the dy matrix to a 2D matrix with the output probabilities that sum to 1. [To note: dy should be iterated through length of it, as it is the output of the network for every input ]
Further a 2D array must be represented into one hot encoding, which will be true_labels (that will represent Binary classes with 0 & 1)

I need both output matrix and true_labels matrix for BCE Loss with following dimensions:

```
output dimension → [4, 2]
true_labels → [4]
```

Any help is most appreciated!
Thank you in advance.

Comment: Instead of providing an image that summarizes the inputs and outputs, it would be a lot more helpful if you could provide a minimal code-formatted text example of the inputs and desired output.

Answer (score 1):

It looks to me that your output is binary so you don't really need a 2D matrix for that task.
Also, I'm not quite sure that the BCE Loss (nor BCEWithLogits) requires tensors of different dimensions, they should both have shape (N, *) [as far as I know](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.nn.BCELoss.html).

Apart from that, for the sake of the question: if you have p(x), you can obtain the other column by simply computing 1 - p(x).

There are many ways to obtain that, a method could be:

```py
# suppose we have a tensor/batch of probabilities
a = torch.tensor([0.4691, 0.9589, 0.7529, 0.9564])
# this gives a 2D matrix with two columns, (1 - p), p
b = torch.stack((1 - p, p), dim=-1)
```

And that's it!